# Using torrent disconnects Internet

Tags: internet-connection, bittorrent

Since yesterday I have a problem on my computer.
If I open a torrent the download starts and speed gets up to about 300kb/s and then it goes back to 0. Then I lose all connectivity, Windows says there's no Internet connection and the only way to get it back is have to reboot the computer. Once I do that everything works fine unless i start downloading a torrent.

I've been using torrents for 10 years and never experienced anything like this.

What I tested:

- It's not the client, it happens with old and new utorrent clients and deluga.
- It's not the router, all other computers on the network have Internet normally, while I go offline.

This is not a case of low speed because the torrent suck up the connection.
Both the torrent and navigation stops and Windows 7 network center says no internet connection, disabling/reenabling the network card has no effect, only reboot fixes it.

Any ideas?

Comment: honestly, i think you have answered by yourself

Comment: Just because your other LAN clients have connection doesn't mean that the router hasn't blocked your machine. I know from experience with a Comcast provided router that their routers have non-user configurable rules or bugs that will block LAN ports. In my case it was a single port which connected to a switch that all my LAN devices connected to. It would decide about 2 times a day to stop communicating on that port. Just replugging the eth cable would wake it up. I had two other devices on the router instead of the switch and they were always still live when the switch connect went down.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set the maximum connections to 10 on your bittorent client.

If it's working, you might want to try a higher number of connections.

I've heard a couple of times, that a too high number of simultaneous connections crashed the internet connection.

Btw: instead of rebooting, you could also try to disable and reenable your network card

Press Win+R and enter into that window

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL ncpa.cpl
```

right-click your Networkconnection and select disable. Wait a couple of seconds, right-click again and enable it. Maybe this will bring your internet connection back ;)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems there is something in your computer that blocks internet when you download torrents.
Maybe its windows (since microsoft said it will shut down pirated software or games (im not saying  you are downloading pirated stuff but maybe microsoft wants to disable the whole p2p system)). anyway its just a guess.

Another thing would be the network administrator have done something to prevent users to download throgh p2p network to stop them from sucking up all the bandwith.

You could try to download torrents through a **Virtual Machine** (I was to tell this as a comment but my rep doesnt gave me the chance) and tell us what happened. If it is downloading normally throgh VM then the problem goes back to your pc/windows and not the network administrator.

as far as I know these kind of weird problems often happen in windows (or mac probably) due to its architecture. you can test it with linux and tell us what happens (or maybe a new windows 7 installation would solve the problem, maybe there is a malware - which came from internet - in your pc causing all the mess).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/369792/after-a-while-downloading-torrents-my-network-card-stops-working-properly?rq=1) right here on the Superuser exchange. I've had similar experiences downloading large amounts of information through via a torrent client. If you have been able to rule out the client and the router, then I recommend trying the steps in the above article.

Additionally, since it's only affecting your computer, you may want to run some tests with your network card. Although I'm not quite sure what causes it, I've noticed Wi-Fi having trouble maintaining long downloads. This is better suited for ethernet, which will have less latency and is less prone to drops, as there is little to no interference when the computer is hard wired into a modem or access point.

If you experience similar issues when downloading through other protocols, such as using FTP or downloading direct through a web browser, you may want to try doing file transfers via your LAN in an attempt to reproduce the problem, with and without Wi-Fi (if that's an option). I understand that some ISPs will throttle your bandwidth after a certain point, since using the maximum bandwidth for long periods of time may appear suspect.

[This article](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch04_:_Simple_Network_Troubleshooting) may help you find out what's going on. It's specific to Linux, however. You can find a Windows article by Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325487). Below are some of the listed causes of interference:

> ```
> NIC duplex and speed incompatibilities
> Network congestion
> Poor routing
> Bad cabling
> Electrical interference
> An overloaded server at the remote end of the connection
> Misconfigured DNS
> ```

Comment: Hi, to clarify the problem happens on a PC connected via lan cable not wifi.